# По будням или в будние дни?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Абонемент действует только по будням? Только в будние дни?

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как правильно употреблять "будние дни" и  возможно ли употребление "будни"?

Напр., *Я могу приехать только в будни?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно в обоих вариантах. Будни - существительное во мн. ч., будние - однокоренное прилагательное.
Будни. "Этимологический словарь Крылова".
Является формой множественного числа существительного будень – "рабочий день", возникшего вследствие слияния словосочетания будьнъ дьнь – "рабочий день". Прилагательное будьнъ произведено от будити – "приводить в состояние бодрствования".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что "будни" — это простое сокращение выражения "будние дни". Так что употребление и того и другого вполне правомерно. "...только по будням" — устойчивое выражение. Звучит немного более официально. Этакий канцеляризм.

Comment: Как раз наоборот. Звучит немного *менее* официально.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что это зависит от того, как и где именно используется выражение.  В Санкт-Петербурге, в тексте расписания электричек, когда-то употреблялось выражение "по будням" или "п.б.". Сейчас пишут -  "по рабочим дням". Наверное, язык ещё не определился, что ему использовать.