# "В будни", "по будням" или "на буднях"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

[Был](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423002/%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8) уже похожий вопрос, но ответы на него, к сожалению, не очень развёрнутые.

Варианты я взял из [вопроса](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8) на Грамоте:

> Вопрос № 249137
>
> Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "в будни", "по будням" или "на буднях"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правильно: *в будни.*

Грамота тоже не объясняет своего ответа.

Авторы ответов на приведённый вопрос с этого сайта считают, что *"по будням"* тоже правильно, в отличие от Грамоты. А как быть с вариантом *"на буднях"?* Допусти́м ли он хотя бы как разговорный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я допускаю *все три варианта*, с разграничением по случаям употребления.

**в будни** - *неопределённое* по времени (неясно, насколько далёкое прошлое, либо будущее) указание на *рабочие* или *ничем не выделяющиеся* (напр. в чьей-то биографии) дни:

> **В будни** своей службы в патентном ведомстве Эйнштейн много задумывался об устройстве мира.

**по будням** - ссылка на устойчивое *расписание* работы ведомства, службы, человека - относительно формально считающимися рабочими дней недели:

> Заявления на отказ от радиоточки принимаются только **по будням**.

**на буднях** - в ближайшие рабочие дни (ср. "на днях" в контексте будущего); выражение можно назвать *неформальным*, употребимым в разговоре о переносе сроков (встречи, сделки) с выходных на один из рабочих дней ближайшей недели; речь может идти об *однократном* событии, в *один* из обозначенных дней:

> В выходной заехать не смогу, встретимся **на буднях**.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Очень убедительно! Доволен также, что "на буднях" не забраковали. :) Очень хотелось так выразиться, и так и сделал, не дождавшись ответа. Контекст был как раз "ближайшие рабочие дни".